# Error while using generic in my Elasticsearch nest client ? it cannot recognize field.Title

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, generics, nest

```
    internal List<T> SearchByText<T>(string index, string searchAgainst, string inquiry) where T : class
    {
        var searchResponse = client.Search<T>(s => s
                    .Index(index)
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(10)
                    .Query(q => q
                         .Match(m => m
                             .Field(f => f.Title)
                            .Query(inquiry)
                         )
                     )
                );

        var products = searchResponse.Documents;

        return (List<T>)products;
    }
```

I have T as my type, so that i can recieve and search all the indexes, but I cannot access the f.Title. cause it is unknown, I understand,  Is there any suggestion to access f.Title?

Error occurs in visual studio -

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no accessible extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can pass title in string  like Field("Title")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that not all `T` that can be passed to the method may have a `Title` property.

You could introduce a generic parameter constraint on `T` to indicate that it must have a `Title` property, perhaps using an interface that defines a `Title` property. You would also then need to implement this interface on any `T` you expect to pass to this method